# How to define multiple similar macro using "##"?

Tags: c, macros

I don't know if there're already some guy asking the same question, but I couldn't find it with the Advanced Search here with [c] [macro] "##".

I want to define multiple macros as follows:

```
#define CHANNEL_0  0
#define CHANNEL_1  1
...
#define CHANNEL_31 31
```

Can I use this symbol ## to do it in a simple way? And How?
Or maybe there're some ways?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Can't it be a single MACRO with an argument? Something like `#define CHANNEL(x) x`.

Comment: You should not be doing this. If a channel number is a channel number, then just use an `int`. There's a reason there's no macros like `INT_FIRST 1` in the C standard library. Don't overengineer things.

Comment: @H2CO3 It's not about overengineering things. It makes the code easier to maintain and understand for other guys. You can't just use pure number.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that "##" is the best solution here. Why not just use *enum*? I see no reason you could not use it if only numbers from 0 to 31 are needed.

```
enum eChannel {
    Channel0, /* evaluates to 0 */
    Channel1, /* evaluates to 1 */
    ...
    Channel31 /* evaluates to 31 */
};
```

And the usage is the same as with *#defines*

```
if(channel == Channel1) do_smth();
```

Comment: With this suggestion, `##` can be used - `enum eChannel { Channel##0`... Though I have no idea why using `##` is of any help.

Comment: @KBart I know enum could save some number typing, what I want to do is save the CHANNEL typing. And 31 is just an example, what if I got 128 Channels?

Comment: Hm, I don't see any easy solution (without some "magic", what is never a good idea for real life projects). But I also don't see, why would you need such *#defines* when you actually only need a single digit. However, if you insist on this, one of the possible solutions would be auto generate header file and include it in your code.